# Meaning of "long-sworded Italian builder"

Tags: meaning

> By the same token, did ye ever hear o' one Torrigiano--Torrisany we
> called him?' 'I can't say I ever did. Was he a Frenchy like?' 'No, a
> hectoring, hard-mouthed, **long-sworded** Italian builder, as vain as
> a peacock and as strong as a bull, but, mark you, a master workman.

This is from "[Rewards and Fairies](http://pinkmonkey.com/dl/library1/digi300.pdf): The Wrong Thing"
by Kipling.

I do not understand what "long-sworded" means.
I have searched in dictionaries but could not find any.

Comment: Possibly https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sworded

Comment: References in books from the 1880's seem to tell us that it usually meant only _armed with a long-sword._

Comment: _Hectoring_ seems to me much more interesting here than long-sworded.

Comment: Hmmm - isn't sword sometimes a metaphor for the male sexual organ? That is what came to my mind when I read the above. Maybe it tells more about me than about Kipling though.... :-)

Comment: @froderick You may not be familiar with Kipling. His were "family" books. He was averse to such rerferences, and there aren't any contemporary usages with that connotation - that I could find, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[M-W defines the -ed suffix](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ed) as meaning

> having : characterized by

It gives the examples "cultured" (i.e., having culture) and "two-legged" (i.e., having two legs). Thus, a "long-sworded" person would be a person who had a long sword. As others have suggested, this might be meant figuratively, but I see no reason why it doesn't carry its literal meaning in your example.

Comment: It probably carries the connotation that he's the sort of man who would not merely carry a sword but is likely to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The Italian builder is described as being "rough" (hard-mouthed) and very strong which would be typical of someone using a [longsword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longsword):

[image: longsword photo]
<sub>(source: [coldsteel-uk.com](https://www.coldsteel-uk.com/store/italian-sword-88its-full-1.jpg))</sub>

The long-sword takes its name from having a long handle not a long blade.  
It is intended for two handed use in combat.

[image: sword poses showing two handed wielding]

The author may have meant the Italian builder was carrying a long-sword, but he might also have meant as a metaphor, that the Italian builder was strong and burly and combative in nature, as one carrying a long-sword would be.

The European Long-Sword, should not be confused with the Japanese Samurai Long-Sword which does get its name from having a long blade.  The katana was always intended to be two-handed.

[image: swords sorted from smallest to largest: tachi, long tachi, nodachi, long nodachi, odachi, long odachi]

Comment: It's very difficult from the usages I could find to ascribe any metaphorical usage to the term. One reference indicated that it might connote _sharp practices_ in business, but I couldn't find any in which there was reference to physical attributes.

Comment: Thank so much for your detailed information. I have got the meaning so well now!!

Comment: @P.E.Dant It would say it's similar to: "[Well don't ask me to go downtown, I won't come back alive. Not only is that mother big but he packs a .45](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/gratefuldead/staggerlee.html)" there are certain implicit meanings in referencing the weapon a person is associated with.

Comment: If you're trying to force a reference to male organs, it's just not there. Kipling, for one thing, would never have used a term with that connotation.

Comment: @P.E.Dant There is no reference to male organs, not sure where you're getting that from, I believe that is only your interpretation. A Colt .45 is a powerful gun, used by people who "mean business". "packs a .45" = "carries a powerful gun"

Comment: If "long-sworded," then, means just "armed with a long sword," that's _explicit,_ not implicit.

Comment: I think if a person is described as "carrying a knife" versus "carrying a long sword" versus "carrying a gun" different images come to mind of what that person is/looks like.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's possible to create (I suppose) an adjective meaning "having or being a thing", from Noun + -ed. Like: "a four-bathroomed house", or "a big-dicked guy", or "a small-nosed bat". It doesn't imply the existence of a verb.

So "[...]-sworded" means "having a sword (of [...] type)". This should help you to understand your passage.